# Internal Routing for Caching in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, varnish

I am using internal routing in my project and use the output urls for caching (Varnish).
Code :

```
_internal:
    resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
    prefix:   /parts
```

and twig (base twig) contains code :
`{% render "my_controller:getHeaderAction" with {}, { "standalone" : true } %}`
`{% render "my_controller:getSidebarAction" with {}, { "standalone" : true } %}`
`{% render "my_controller:getFooterAction" with {}, { "standalone" : true } %}`

this generates the urls like :
`/parts/my_controller%3AgetHeaderAction/none.html`
`/parts/my_controller%3AgetSidebarAction/none.html`
`/parts/my_controller%3AgetFooterAction/none.html`

I was trying to get separate Url for SidebarAction like :
`/parts/prefix/my_controller%3AgetSidebarAction/none.html`

but couldn't figure out how to do it, because internal routing auto-generates urls.
Any workaround for this?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually define route rule for `my_controller:getSidebarAction` and then render it with `url` tag.

Assuming you're using Symfony 2.3, the syntax would be

`{{ render_esi(url('latest_news', { 'max': 5 })) }}`

Notice I'm using special `render_esi` tag, this was added in Symfony 2.2 to add better ESI support for reverse proxies like Varnish.

More info here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-esi-in-symfony2